# Key Évents on textbox ,button and progressbar?

Tags: c#, keyevent

I have a textbox, a button, and a progressbar. I would like the keydown event of the textbox therefore the entry, is found using a button in the progressbar, in fact I would like the number entered in the textbox to become the value of the progressbar and that in this case the progressbar value increases. If you could put me a sample code, that would be nice, thank you.

```cs
    public void button1_Click(object 
    sender,EventArgs e)
    {
    //I don't know.
    }


    public void textbox2_KeyDown(object 
    sender,KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    if(e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad0 || 
    e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad9) 
    {
     // I don't know !
    }
```

Comment: can you clarify please ?

Comment: I want to be able to read the keyboard entries and with a button on which we click to be able to progress the progressbar by the entered value. Do you understand ?

Comment: Hi, can you please confirm if the below solution answered your question if yes [please mark as resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

*On KeyDown capture the keyValue*

```
int keyValue { get; set; }

private void textbox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

  int keyVal = (int)e.KeyValue; keyValue = -1;

  if ((keyVal >= (int)Keys.D0 && keyVal <= (int)Keys.D9))
  {
      keyValue = (int)e.KeyValue - (int)Keys.D0;
  }
  else if (keyVal >= (int)Keys.NumPad0 && keyVal <= (int)Keys.NumPad9)
  {
      keyValue = (int)e.KeyValue - (int)Keys.NumPad0;
  }
}
```

*On Button Click Increase the ProgessBar value*

```
public void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   //Here Increment the progress bar by keyValue
    progressBar1.Value += keyValue;
}
```

[*KeyValues and KeyCodes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to change the progress bar value based on the textBox input and detect that change.
Well, to get the input from the textBox on change, there is an event for that which called: 
[TextChanged](http://TextChanged)

so with every change in the input, you'll be able to capture the input.
For the progressbar, you can change the value by the property: Value.
Read more:
[ProgressBar.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value?view=netframework-4.8)
so if your progressBar control named: progressBar1, change it by:

```
progressBar1.Value = 5; // here the value is 5.
```

Now, you can use textChanged event to set the progress bar value like:

```
public void textbox2_TextChanged(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{
   progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); // parse the input to int value. Consider using int.TryParse     
}
```